# refused my local machine sql connection for 1433 port

Tags: sql-server, azure, hybrid

I'm trying to connect sql server using following connection string but getting error:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" 
       connectionString="Server=MyMachine32\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Database=MembershipDB;User ID=sa;Password=mydata@123" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Error:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I have already enabled TCP/IP from Sql server configuration manager.
what else needed?

Comment: You aren't using a local address at all. Use `.\SQLEXPRESS`, `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` or even `127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS`. By using a computer name you are actually making a *remote* connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tagged your question with "Azure".

So, check if in Azure settings there is a rule to grant at your machine access on DB hosted in Azure space.

You can go [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/), a guide about Azure firewall rule.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the **Firewall** setting, most likely it is stopping it. Try to turn off your Firewall and check if it works. Also it may be that the process which is hosting the service is not listening on that port.