# Cannot conect to azure Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2012

I already tried many things:

- Firewall Exception
- Named Pipes enables
- TCP/IP Enabled and 1443 port open.

And I still got this error all the time

> Cannot connect to ip.database.windows.net.
>   ERROR : (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 – Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53 )

This is driving me crazy, because I need this connection to do some reports about that data.

Thanks.

Comment: So, what is the programming problem? Stackoverflow is sort of dedicated to PROGRMAMING - system administration has sister sites, you know.

Comment: What is the Connection String you are using and with which language?

Comment: SQL Server default port is 1433.

Comment: maybe duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775810/refused-my-local-machine-sql-connection-for-1433-port/33775937#33775937

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I turned off the firewall and it worked. Now I'm using SQL Server Data Tools and the error still pop ups.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the firewall rules don't include the proper client IP that you think it does. Use SQL Server Management Studio to attempt to access to your database on Azure.

Look at the error message that pops up. It should have an IP address in it. Now look at the list of IP addresses that you have in your firewall settings and make sure that the proper IP is in there.

I'm suggesting this because I had the same problem, while I was connected in an office network through a VPN, and the wrong IP was showing up. Once I added the IP that it actually resolved for my client connection, I was able to get access to the SQL Server database without any issues.